# Error on data visualize on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry for my bad english, but I've this problem, for visualize some data from db I've make a Helper file, for manipulate and set the visualization and one Model for extract the rows from a DB and grouped all by date.
the problem is the Model return 0 (on :price) but the DB is full.

THIS IS THE HELPER:

```
module RoomsHelper
  def rooms_chart_data(start = 3.weeks.ago)
    rooms_by_day = Room.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      {
          reservation: date,
          price: rooms_by_day[date].try(:total_price) || 0
      }
    end
  end
end
```

THIS IS THE MODEL:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    rooms = where(reservation: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
    rooms = rooms.group("date(reservation)")
    rooms = rooms.select("sum(price) as total_price, reservation")
    rooms.group_by { |o| o.reservation.to_date }
  end
end
```

AND I PASTE THE OUTPUT WRONG:

```
     <div id="year_chart" data-rooms="[{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-22&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},
{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-23&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-24&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-25&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-26&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-27&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-28&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-29&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-30&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-07-31&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-01&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-02&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-03&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-04&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-05&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-06&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-07&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-08&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-09&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-10&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-11&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0},{&quot;reservation&quot;:&quot;2015-08-12&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:0}]"
```

THIS IS THE DB TABLE:

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.integer :identity_room
      t.integer :price
      t.integer :guest
      t.datetime :reservation
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

AFTER ADD .to_s

```
module RoomsHelper
  def rooms_chart_data(start = 3.weeks.ago)
    rooms_by_day = Room.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      {
          reservation: date,
          price: rooms_by_day[date.to_s].try(:total_price) || 0
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the date to a string in the `group(date(reservation))` and then trying to look up items in the hash with the string coerced date instead, e.g.  `rooms_by_day[date.to_s]` rather than `rooms_by_day[date]`

Comment: have you tried adding `to_s` within `Room.total_grouped_by_day` as well?
Something like `rooms.group_by { |o| o.reservation.to_date.to_s }`.
On top of that, try dumping the content of the object `rooms_by_day` within `RoomsHelper.rooms_chart_data`, so you can understand which keys compose that hash.
I can suggest you to insert a `binding.pry` after the initialisation of that variable. This requires adding Pry to the Gemfile:

    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'pry-rescue'